# How to chaining mapred and mapreduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, chaining

Now I have two hadoop jobs need to chain together. One is Mapred job(old api), the other is Mapreduce job(new API), this is because the external library we used for these two jobs.

I want to know whether there is a good way to chain these two jobs.

I have tried one way (first run the mapred job with JobClient.runjob(), after it finished run the second one.) But there is a problem for me submit this job to the hadoop clustor. If I close my local terminal, then only the first job will run, the second won't. It is because the Java code is running locally, so is there a good solution for this? Then I can just submit the whole job to cluster, the local program not need to keep running.

Comment: May be you can look at oozie or cascading..

Comment: So, you want your job2 to strictly follow job1?

Comment: @JtheRocker Yes, I want the job2 to follow the job1. What strictly follows mean. The thing I want to do is like one submission, then these two jobs will be done.

Comment: If you release your local terminal, your job1 followed by job2 should run in cluster, right? You can try probably try nohup to do that. I can provide an answer how you can do that using nohup, if that's what you want. Thanks!